# Idiomatic string rotation in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, rotation, burrows-wheeler-transform

How to idiomatically rotate a string in Clojure for the [Burrows-Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform)?

I came up with this, which uses `(cycle "string")`, but feels a bit imperative:

```
(let [s (str "^" "banana" "|")
      l (count s)
      c (cycle s)
      m (map #(take l (drop % c)) (range l))]
  (apply map str m))
=> ("^banana|" "banana|^" "anana|^b" "nana|^ba" "ana|^ban" "na|^bana" "a|^banan" "|^banana")
```

I'm not sure if this qualifies as code golf. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: On an efficiency basis Criterium's quickbench gave average run times of cgrand/status203/pate's answers in a rough ratio of 1:7:46

Comment: @status20, @O-I's `rotations` solution is even faster by a factor of 4.

Comment: @pate rotations returns a lazy seq of lazy seqs of chars. When I force evaluation (`(dorun (apply str (rotations "^bananas|")))` vs `(dorun (bwrot "bananas"))`) `rotations` is 12x slower than `bwrot`.

Answer (score 5):

I would do:

```
(defn bwrot [s]
  (let [s (str "^" s "|")]
    (for [i (range (count s))]
      (str (subs s i) (subs s 0 i)))))
```

or:

```
(defn bwrot [s]
  (let [n (+ 2 (count s))
        s (str "^" s "|^" s "|")]
    (for [i (range n)]
      (subs s i (+ i n)))))
```

The second one should allocate less (one string instead of three per iteration).

Comment: Since Java 7, substrings are no longer views.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I didn't know about that change (which apparently happened in 7u6)

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a [`rotations`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure-contrib/seq-api.html#clojure.contrib.seq/rotations) function in `clojure.contrib.seq` that might be worth a look for inspiration. The [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/b8d2743d3a89e13fc9deb2844ca2167b34aaa9b6/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/seq.clj#L129-L137) is reproduced below:

```
(defn rotations
  "Returns a lazy seq of all rotations of a seq"
  [x]
  (if (seq x)
    (map
     (fn [n _]
       (lazy-cat (drop n x) (take n x)))
     (iterate inc 0) x)
    (list nil)))
```

Then you could do something like:

```
(apply map str (rotations "^banana|"))
; => ("^banana|" "banana|^" "anana|^b" "nana|^ba" "ana|^ban" "na|^bana" "a|^banan" "|^banana")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I was unconcerned about efficiency or number of characters I'd write something like:

```
(defn rotate-string
 [s]
 (apply str (concat (drop 1 s) (take 1 s))))

(defn string-rotations
  [s] 
  (->> s
       (iterate rotate-string)
       (take (count s))))

(rotate-string "^banana|") ; "banana|^"
(string-rotations "^banana|") ; ("^banana|" "banana|^" "anana|^b" "nana|^ba" "ana|^ban" "na|^bana" "a|^banan" "|^banana")
```

In particular, factoring out the single rotation into its own function.

Answer (score 1):

A stepped call to `partition` works:

```
(defn bwt[s]
  (let [s' (str "^" s "|")
        c (cycle s')
        l (count s')]
    (map last (sort (apply map str (take l (partition l 1 c)))))))

(apply str (bwt "banana"))
=> "|bnn^aaa"
```

Comment: This is 72x slower than @O-I's `rotations` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish rotation is to use a "double string" (i.e. concatenate the string to itself) and play around with substrings.

```
(defn rotations [strng]
  (let [indices (range (count strng))
        doublestr (str strng strng)]
    (map #(subs doublestr % (+ % (count strng))) indices)))

(rotations "^banana|")
;;(^banana| banana|^ anana|^b nana|^ba ana|^ban na|^bana a|^banan |^banana)
```

Rotations of "foo":

- Take the double string "foofoo"
- Length `n` of "foo" = 3
- The rotations are all the `n` substrings of "foofoo" that start with `indices` 0, 1, 2 and have the same length `n`